# Hanging indent on item in description list with enumitem

Tags: enumitem, description

With `enumitem`, how can I get the single item in the `oneproperty` description list to have a hanging indent, just like the items in the `propertylist` enumerate list?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newlist{proplis}{enumerate}{1}
\newenvironment{propertylist}[1]{%
  \setlist[proplis,1]{%
  wide,leftmargin=*,label=\textsf{\upshape(#1\arabic*)}}\begin{proplis}%
  \itshape}
  {\end{proplis}}

% Hack for labeled items in description list
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\enit@description@i}{%
  \labelsep\z@
}{%
  \phantomsection
  \let\org@label\label
  \let\label\@gobble
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{##1}%
  \let\label\org@label
  \labelsep\z@
}{}{\undefined}
\makeatother

% NB: must enclose actual item name in parens, \label[...] in optional arg!
\newlist{oneproplis}{description}{1}
\newenvironment{oneproperty}[1]{%
\setlist[oneproplis,1]{%
    font=\normalfont\textsf,
    itemindent=0pt,
    wide,leftmargin=*,
    itemsep=0pt,topsep=2pt,
    format={\normalfont\textsf},
    }\begin{oneproplis}%
  \itshape}
  {\end{oneproplis}}


\begin{document}

A thingamajig is an object having properties:
\begin{propertylist}{O}

\item This is the penultimate and next-to-last property, which precedes the last property but follows any other property. 
%And we could repeat ourselves: This is the penultimate and next-to-last property, which precedes the last property but follows any other property.

\item This is final!.

\end{propertylist}

Much simpler is the property:

\begin{oneproperty}

\item[(SN)]\label{property:SN}

This is a list that has just one item, set up as a description list and configured so as to take an argument that will become its name.

\end{oneproperty}

\end{document}
```

[image: Want hanging indent on "oneproperty" description list item.]

The amount of the indent should depend on the width of the item's label, of course.

**Idea for a solution**

Is there some way to "fake" this, using an `enumerate` list but suppressing the number — something like ...

```
\newlist{oneproplis}{enumerate}{1}
\newenvironment{onepropertylist}[1]{%
\setlist[newoneproplis,1]{% 
   wide,leftmargin=*,
   label=\textsf{\upshape(#1)\swallow}}\begin{oneproplis}%
   \itshape}%
   {\end{oneproplis}}
```

... where `\swallow` has the same role that, say `\arabic` would have but, instead of formatting the item's number, just suppresses it?

Comment: The `wide` key is supposed to produce items that look like ordinary paragraphs. I think it is contradictory to what you want here.

Comment: @RuixiZhang: But the `wide` key does do what I want for `propertylist`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution if you know the widest  description label:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newlist{proplis}{enumerate}{1}
\newenvironment{propertylist}[1]{%
  \setlist[proplis,1]{%
  wide,leftmargin=*,label=\textsf{\upshape(#1\arabic*)}}\begin{proplis}%
  \itshape}
  {\end{proplis}}

% Hack for labeled items in description list
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\enit@description@i}{%
  \labelsep\z@
}{%
  \phantomsection
  \let\org@label\label
  \let\label\@gobble
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{##1}%
  \let\label\org@label
  \labelsep\z@
}{}{\undefined}
\makeatother
\newlength{\desclabelwd}
\settowidth{\desclabelwd}{\textsf{(SN)}}
% NB: must enclose actual item name in parens, \label[...] in optional arg!\dimexpr7mm + \labelsep\relax,
\newlist{oneproplis}{description}{1}
\newenvironment{oneproperty}[1]{%
\setlist[oneproplis,1]{%
    font=\normalfont\textsf,
    wide, leftmargin=\dimexpr\parindent+\desclabelwd+\labelsep,
    itemsep=0pt, topsep=2pt,
    format={\normalfont\textsf},
    }\begin{oneproplis}%
  \itshape}
  {\end{oneproplis}}

\begin{document}

A thingamajig is an object having properties: A thingamajig is an object having properties:
\begin{propertylist}{O}

\item This is the penultimate and next-to-last property, which precedes the last property but follows any other property.
%And we could repeat ourselves: This is the penultimate and next-to-last property, which precedes the last property but follows any other property.

\item This is final!.

\end{propertylist}

Much simpler is the property:

\begin{oneproperty}

\item[(SN)]\label{property:SN}

This is a list that has just one item, set up as a description list and configured so as to take an argument that will become its name. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{oneproperty}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do know the widest such description label, so that will work. Is there some way, though, to modify the environment so that the parentheses around the label are automatically inserted?

Comment: This gives a *fixed*-length hanging indentation for all such one-item description lists, with the hanging indentation fixed at the width of `\desclabelwd`. But I need a *variable*-length hanging indentation, which will vary according to the width of the particular label. Thus if in the `\begin{oneproperty}`...`\end{oneproperty}`I use `\item[(S)]` or `\item[(SN)]` or `\item[(SNXYZ)]` I need different amounts.

Comment: You can use `\settowidth{\desclabelwd}{your label}}` before each such environment. I tried to incorporate it with an optional argument at the beginning of the environment ((which would be the ideal solution), but couldn't make it work.